# Memory allocation - Common memory for a process tree

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I have to write a code such that, it may create child process via Createprocess API.
Parent process in the process tree has to allocate the memory common to the total process tree, so that child process can access it.

Malloc, globalalloc does allocate memory within the scope for the process. However I could not extend it for the child process. Was there any APIs in Windows to allocate memory specific for a process tree. If not, Is there any API to allocate memory as a session image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to share memory across processes under Windows is through [memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx). Don't be thrown off by the word "file"; there doesn't have to be a file under the memory (other than the swap file).

Comment: Thanks steve, I am checking it.

Comment: Steve, it looks its a .Net Implementation. Was there any Native support for this concept?

Comment: Sorry about that; I changed the link to point to the OS-level description in the SDK. The .NET stuff just wraps it.

Comment: fantastic. Lemme try this. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: I could set the value in memory, it is reflected in file after close handle. However write file doesnot work out.. Please find the below code, it says error_invalid_handle Code:--> main(){
    HANDLE hmap1 =  OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_WRITE,false,"MyMapping"); 
char *m = "Insert text"; 
DWORD count; 
BOOL c= WriteFile(hmap1,m,10,&count,NULL); 
DWORD e= GetLastError(); 
void *k = MapViewOfFile(hmap1,FILE_MAP_WRITE,0,0,0); 
c= WriteFile((HANDLE)k,m,10,&count,NULL); 
e= GetLastError(); 
int l = fputs("Insert text",(FILE*)k); 
UnmapViewOfFile(k); 
CloseHandle(hmap1); 
return 0; 
}

Comment: Look at the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx